# AsyncTask doesn't invoke onPostExecute()

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I am writing an `AsyncTask` as below:

```
class Load extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
//do job seconds
//stop at here, and does not run onPostExecute
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
super.onPostExecute(unused);
wait = false;
new Load().execute();
}
}
```

And the other method as below:

```
public void click() {
new Load().execute();
while(wait) {
;
}
}
```

The wait is a global boolean value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code:

```
public void click() {
new Load().execute();
while(wait) {
;
}
}
```

will block the UI thread while the task executes. This is as bad as just running the background task in the foreground and should cause an Application Not Responding (ANR) error. Please don't do it.

Note that `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()` will not be called if the task is cancelled. It also won't be called if `doInBackground` throws an exception. Whatever is going on in `doInBackground` may be causing this.

Answer (score 3):

this is proppar way asynctask, you wont to use wait in any other method or sleep both are
use same normal method

```
private class AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your `doInBackground()` method is throwing an `Exception`, try putting it in a `try-catch` block.
Also I don't know why you are calling `super.onPostExecute()`, try removing this too, it's not necessary to use this statement.

Answer (score 2):

Your `while(wait){}` loop is blocking the UI thread. `onPostExecute` runs on the UI thread. Since you're blocking, `onPostExecute` can never execute. Additionally you're creating a new instance of the `Load` `AsyncTask` and executing it in `onPostExecute`, meaning you'll have an infinite loop of these unless you cancel at some point.